# Android SIP API - After SipAudioCall.Listener.onRingingBack() ,how to hear any waiting sound

Tags: android, api, sip

I'm developing a SIP client app using Android 2.3+ API, I can make a outgoing call and receive a incoming call successfully by using SipDemo sample codes. but I can't hear any thing before peer answers the call. 
   As we know, when we make an ordinary GSM call, we can hear "DO..DO...DO" before the person you called answers your calling.
   Now let me show you my SipAudioCall.Listener code. I know SipAudioCall.Listener.onRingingBack was called when peer received the invite,and SipAudioCall.Listener.onCallEstablished was called when peer answered.
   I don't know what to do in SipAudioCall.ListeneronRingingBack method to hear any thing. when I make a call, my side is silent until peer answers my calling...(Sorry for my poor english)

Thanks in advance!

```
private final SipAudioCall.Listener sipAudioCallListener = new SipAudioCall.Listener(){

    @Override
    public void onRinging(SipAudioCall call, SipProfile caller) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onRinging caller="+caller.getUriString()+"; call="+call.getState()+"; caller="+caller.getUriString());
        super.onRinging(call, caller);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRingingBack(SipAudioCall call) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onRingingBack: call="+call.getState());
        super.onRingingBack(call);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCallEstablished: call="+call.getState());
        super.onCallEstablished(call);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCallEnded: call="+call.getState());
        super.onCallEnded(call);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallBusy(SipAudioCall call) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCallBusy: call="+call.getState());
        super.onCallBusy(call);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallHeld(SipAudioCall call) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCallHeld: call="+call.getState());
        super.onCallHeld(call);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(SipAudioCall call, final int errorCode, final String errorMessage) {
        Log.e(TAG, "###onError errorCode="+errorCode+"; errorMessage="+errorMessage);
        super.onError(call, errorCode, errorMessage);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChanged(final SipAudioCall call) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onChanged: call="+call.getState());
        super.onChanged(call);
    switch(call.getState()){
        case SipSession.State.OUTGOING_CALL:
        //making an outgoing call 
            break;
        case SipSession.State.OUTGOING_CALL_RING_BACK: 
        //peer receives ringing event, what can I do to hear any thing until peer answers the call??
        //...
            break;
        case SipSession.State.IN_CALL:
        //call established, it works fine.
            call.startAudio();
            call.setSpeakerMode(false);
            if(call.isMuted()){
                call.toggleMute();
            }
            break;
        case SipSession.State.READY_TO_CALL:
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope you already have found a solution. If not try the following:

Use the `MediaPlayer` in the `onRingBack()` method and play your own sound. Make sure that you stop the `MediaPlayer` after the call is established. In this example I used a MP3 file placed in my `raw` ressources.

```
SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener() {

    @Override
    public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call) {  
        mPlayer.stop();
        call.startAudio();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRingingBack (SipAudioCall call){
        MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.phone_calling); 
        mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mPlayer.start();
    }

};
```